# iFrame in vs2010 vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to insert a iFrame into my web form.
And i have a list of data from my database.
It uses a sql data source to retrieve the data in the data base.
I would want to bind it to the src of iFrame is that possible?
I tried doing it but it doesnt give me a way to bind it.

Comment: I guess i didn't understand you well ... are we talking about the same iframe element which we use it to show a certain url content on a certain place in your page ?

Comment: Yes.. I am using that to show the google map API

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) tag defines an inline frame that contains another document.

So if i were you i would create a new page which has a data control within its body which you would bind that data into it.

Then you would link it to the iframe

```
<iframe src="SomePage.aspx" width="100%" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: hmm is it possible to display it from the database?

Comment: Yes create a page that retrieves your data, then use this data to call google's api, and finally use page's link with the ifram tag.

Comment: My database also have the Goggle Map API stored in it. And my page load retrieve a list of API

Comment: I didn't understand .. I guess you didn't read the Google's API documentation ... Are you trying to use the API to locate a certain point of the map?

Comment: Yes is a specific location on the map

Comment: Well i guess you need to try reading this article http://www.mikeborozdin.com/post/Working-with-Google-Maps-API-in-ASPNET.aspx